# How to style a table in a vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to style the table in this vue component, my understanding is that I need to create the css from the data function and then bind it to the appropriate element in the template.

What I am trying to do is apply the following css to my table

css:

```
 .table-striped>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: #f9f9f9
 }
```

vue component:

```
Vue.component('overview', {
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    props: ['job_execs'],
    template: `
      <div overview>
      <h3>Overview</h3>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>Start Time</td>
          <td>[[ job_execs[0].time_start ]]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>End Time</td>
          <td>[[ job_execs[0].time_end ]]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Job</td>
          <td>http://placeholder</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            divExample: {
                color: 'red',
                fontSize: '13px'
                }
        }
    },
});
```

Im not sure how to 1.  create this CSS from the data function and 2.  Bind it within the template.

I am currently working on a project where I need to take an existing web app and convert the front end to vue.js and it seems like its going to be a real headache extracting the css I need from the already bloated css that exists and then converting it to vue js functions that inject that css per component.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind css properties to a tag in Vue using the following way:

```
<tr>
    <td>Start Time</td>
    <td>[[ job_execs[0].time_start ]]</td>
</tr>
<tr v-bind:style="strippedTr">
    <td>End Time</td>
    <td>[[ job_execs[0].time_end ]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Job</td>
    <td>http://placeholder</td>
</tr>

...

data: function() {
    return {
        strippedTr: {
            'background-color': '#f9f9f9'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show how it would be using your code.